# can't override a column in a block by preference

Tags: magento2

in my case i want to delete a column 'Status' ,my problem is that i can't remove it by preference in di.xml

the preference override it works fine with other methods but this method no , i dont know why

> this file is Mymodule\Dealer\Block\Adminhtml\Dealer\Grid\Reports

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('m_increment_id', array(
            'header'       => __('Order #'),
            'width'        => '100',
            'index'        => 'm_increment_id',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.increment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('m_created_at', array(
            'header'       => __('Purchase On'),
            'index'        => 'm_created_at',
            'type'         => 'm_datetime',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        ));

          //$this->addColumn('status', array(
           // 'header'       => __('Status'),
           // 'index'        => 'm_status',
           // 'filter_index' => 'main_table.status',
           // 'type'         => 'options',
            //'width'        => '70px',
//            'options'      => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
       // ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

> the file for override in di.xml

```
<preference for="\Amasty\Perm\Block\Adminhtml\Dealer\Grid\Reports"
                type="Mymodule\Dealer\Block\Adminhtml\Dealer\Grid\Reports" />
```

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call `return parent::_prepareColumns();` and in that parent class in that method the status column is again declared.
Maybe try to override method like this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    $this->removeColumn('status');
}
```

or just remove `return parent::_prepareColumns();` in your code. But the first solution in better.

Comment: thank you bro , it work but with just return parent::_prepareColumns(); , but when i add this it didn't work , they tell to me "'Unreachable statement "

Comment: probably the parent metod return $this so, modify the metod like this: ```protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $return = parent::_prepareColumns();
    $return->removeColumn('status');
    return $return;
}```

Comment: yes it work thanks a lot

Comment: how can i see what does parent::_prepareColumns(); contain , i have do vardump() to it but it didn't work

Comment: Better tool to verify the content of the returned method is use the xdebug. But you can simply read the parent code and you should be able to understand what happened there - go to the parent class you override it’s located under vendor/magento directory.